# How to compare strings in Python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

If the text i am printing from that element is the correct the code just passes over it

```
     for items2 in ListaPlajePariuri:
         NumePlaje = items2.find_element_by_class_name(
                                    'KambiBC-bet-offer-category__title js-bet-offer-category-title')
         TotalGoluri = items2.find_elements_by_class_name(
                                    'KambiBC-bet-offer-subcategory KambiBC-bet-offer-subcategory--overunder')
         print(NumePlaje.text)


         if NumePlaje.text == 'Timp regulamentar' :
             input("why will you not work?")
             NumePlaje.click()
```

here is a printscreen with the  output from `print(NumePlaje.text)`, which seems to be good

[image]

Comment: Maybe the text has a trailing space?  Try printing it like this: `print('|%s|' % NumePlaje.text)`

Comment: Printscreen output is hard to read. When you post text in your SO questions please do it the way you did you Python code.

Comment: Following the idea of @JohnGordon, you could test for that string using `if 'Timp regulamentar' in NumePlaje.text:`. This way it wouldn't matter what else is in `NumePlaje.text`.

Comment: @JohnGordon this is the new output         |Timp regulamentar |, and i tried to compare it with this one and still passes over it

Comment: @BillBell your suggestion worked, if you write an answer i will accept it, thanks

Comment: @JohnGordon, would you like to write the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I will withdraw this answer if John Gordon indicates that he wants to answer.*

John Gordon pointed out that the variable `NumePlaje.text` might have trailing white space. This being the case, a simple test for `NumePlaje.text == 'Timp regulamentar'` would fail even if the variable contained that string.

Then a test for the presence of this string should be:

```
if 'Timp regulamentar' in NumePlaje.text:
```

This version of the `if` asks whether the string appears anywhere within the variable.